# How to cancel a pthread without cancellation point

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, pthread-join

I use a 3rd-party-library (dcerpc) for my application being a rpc server.
Let's say the 3rd party function are in the namespace third.

I call third::listen in a thread, in order to listen for incoming requests.

"Third" provides all the mechanisms to interrupt this listen and properly exit the thread, but either it doesn't work, or I don't do it the correct way.
I first try everything with the library tools (demo sample, mail-list, browse the source code to understand...) but with no success.

So I try an alternative: violently kill the listening thread.
But third::listen has no cancellation point, I guess.

So this code (I simulate third::listen with listen function above):

```
void* listen(void*)
{
    cout << "listening for calls...." << endl;

    while (true) {}
    printf ("Server stoppped listening\n");
    return 0;
}


int main()
{

    pthread_t thread = 0;

    int res = pthread_create(&thread, 0, listen, 0);
    cout << "pthread_create res: " << res << endl;

    sleep(1);

    bool isThreadRunning = (pthread_tryjoin_np(thread, 0) != 0);
    cout << "Thread is running: " << isThreadRunning << endl;

    res = pthread_cancel(thread);
    cout << "pthread_cancel res: " << res << endl;

    sleep(1);

    isThreadRunning = (pthread_tryjoin_np(thread, 0) != 0);
    cout << "Thread is running: " << isThreadRunning << endl;

    res = pthread_join(thread, 0);
    cout << "pthread_join res: " << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

will output:

```
pthread_create res: 0
listening for calls....

Thread is running: 1
pthread_cancel res: 0
Thread is running: 1
```

and pthread_join(thread, 0) blocks (logic because no cancellation point).

My question: how to kill this thread !!

I tried with signals, but it stops my whole process, not only the thread.

My last try will be to isolate the listening in a dedicated fork process, but in my project context, it's really a pain to fork (that's another story).

Thanks a lot for any help.

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a thread can be cancelled depends on its cancellation *state* and *type*. The default state is `enabled`. So that's fine. But the default type is `deferred`. That means when you send the thread a cancellation request, it's deferred until it reaches a cancellation point. Since your thread doesn't do anything in the empty loop, it doesn't reach a cancellation point at all. Hence, it doesn't respond to `pthread_cancel()`.

You can set the cancellation type of the thread to `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS` which will typically make the thread exit. Call

```
pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, 0);
```

before the loop.

Or you can call one of the functions that's a cancellation point. For example, do `fflush(stdout);` inside the loop.

POSIX list a number of functions as cancellation point. See [cancellation points](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) for such a list.

I can't make any comment on the "3rd party" library that doesn't respond to exiting threads with the limited information you have given.

Comment: Thank you !!!! I read about the cancellation type, but didn't get the asynchronous type makes the stuff.
Thanks!